# Application Insights is not including properties set by custom ITelemetryInitializer

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

*(Added **UPDATE 1** below which I think answers this question)*

In a fairly simple ASP.NET Core 2 web app I have initialized in `Program` like this:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseApplicationInsights()
        .Build();
```

I haven't configured an instrumentation key in `appSettings.json` yet because for now I'm running locally. When I run my app and force an exception on load of my home page I can see the exception logged in Visual Studio's telemetry search for Application Insights.

[image]

I now want to capture some details about the request in every logged event. I've followed some guidance and created an implementation of `ITelemetryInitializer`:

```
public class CustomTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    private const string UserIdKey = "UserId";

    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public CustomTelemetryInitializer(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        if (!(telemetry is RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry)) return;

        var props = requestTelemetry.Properties;

        if (!props.ContainsKey(UserIdKey))
        {
            var user = _userService.GetCurrentUser();

            if (user != null)
            {
                props.Add(UserIdKey, user.UserId);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is largely following [this guide](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Custom-Configuration). `IUserService` is just a service which uses `IHttpContextAccessor` to get the current `ClaimsPrincipal`. You can see I'm trying to add the user's ID to the custom telemetry properties.

I've registered this `ITelemetryInitializer` in `Startup` like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, CustomTelemetryInitializer>();
```

When I run my app again, I can see the debugger running through `CustomTelemetryInitializer` and setting the property correctly. However, when I review the events logged in app insights, the custom property is not included. They look identical to the screenshot above.

I've tried moving the app insights initialization out of `Program` and instead initializing it in `Startup` after registering the `ITelemetryInitializer` using `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry()`, but this makes no difference.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1**

I've realised I made a mistake. My custom properties *are* being included for Request events after all. But not the Exception events. But I've now realised that these Exception events take a different implementation of `ITelemetry` in `Initialize` i.e. `TraceTelemetry`. So I hadn't realised I was excluding these events from my custom properties.

Answer (score 5):

Glad you figured it out.
All `ITelemetry` implementations in the SDK implements, `ISupportProperties` which gives it `Properties` collection. If you want to attach properties to every telemetry, you can cast to `ISupportProperties` and set props.